# Unexpected aliasing with std::experimental::directory_iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, std-filesystem, c++-experimental

I was using the experimental `std::filesystem` implementation in gcc 6.3.1, and ran into some very unexpected behavior with regard to `std::experimental::filesystem::directory_iterator` and `std::distance`. Specifically, after a call to `std::distance`, the original iterator appeared to have been modified.

After a bunch of fruitless debugging trying to find a logical error in my code, I started digging around in the implementation of `directory_iterator`, and finally found that the iterator uses `std::shared_ptr` internally, has a default copy-constructor, and I assume that `operator++` must be directly incrementing the managed pointer.

The following code reproduces the issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/filesystem>
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

int main() {
  auto it = fs::directory_iterator("/etc");
  std::cout << *it << std::endl;
  std::distance(it, fs::directory_iterator{});
  std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

As this kind of implementation yields wildly counter-intuitive results whenever passing to a function that expects iterators with traditional value-semantics (all of the STL algorithms, as far as I know), I have a hard time believing this is intended behavior, but am hesitant to call a bug.

Obviously, this API was experimental at the time of release, but I was thinking it was intended to be a faithful implementation of the filesystem TS. I don't have access to a compiler with full `C++17` support, so I had been hoping to use this in the intervening time.

Is this intended behavior, and should I expect `directory_iterator` to work this way in future releases? For the time being I guess I can use `boost::filesystem`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[directory_iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator) are defined to be [InputIterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator) and therefore can only be used once. There is no const addition operator so you have to use the increment operator which modifies the iterator.

Comment: I thought I understood the distinction between input and bidirectional iterators, but I take your point. The bit I was missing was (emphasis mine): "once an InputIterator i has been incremented, ALL COPIES of its previous value may be invalidated." I assumed copy-constructed InputIterators could be safely advanced without touching other instances, but turns out that's a ForwardIterator. Thanks!

Comment: I assume this limitation is to allow simple implementation on top of the underlying OS directory listing APIs which often only allow forward iteration over their results.

Comment: I was actually just thinking the same thing. To my knowledge, opendir/readdir only allow for forward iteration.